# How to set the default server for RDF4J workbench?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, dns, rdf4j

*Imagine* I have a RDF4J server and workbench running on an AWS server at `http://1.2.3.4`

...and I recently registered the domain `example.com` via AWS route 53 and pointed it to `http://1.2.3.4`  My AWS security group has all ports open for the laptop I'm using now.

If I use a web browser to visit `http://example.com:8080/rdf4j-server`, the expected web interface comes up immediately.

However, if I try to visit `http://example.com:8080/rdf4j-workbench`, the page takes roughly one minute to load.  Once it does, the `RDF4J Server URL` is set to `http://example.com:8080/rdf4j-server`.  Clicking any of the exploration links on the left lead to `waiting...`

If I change the `RDF4J Server URL` to `http://localhost:8080/rdf4j-server` in the web interface, then I am able to browse, explore, query, etc.

Is there a way to set the workbench's default server?  I didn't see any parameter files that look relevant in my RDF4J home `/opt/tomcat/.RDF4J`  I didn't see any errors in the log files in that folder, either.

There are timeout errors in catalina.out that might be relevant:

```
23-May-2017 14:45:09.597 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.eclipse.rdf4j.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator.canConnect java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

I am also open to name-resolution tricks.  I added the following line to `/etc/hosts`.  That seems to work, but it seems a little too sneaky for my taste.

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not immediately sure why using the example.com server address from the Workbench fails when direct access clearly works.

But as for how to configure the server address the Workbench uses: it's normally extrapolated from the location of the Workbench (that is, if it's on the same host), or if that doesn't work, the Workbench leaves it empty until you manually fill it out. Once set though, the value should be saved in a browser cookie, so upon next visit you shouldn't have to re-enter it.

If that fails either your browser is configured to reject cookies, or you may have found a bug.

Comment: Thanks.  You've offered some clarification and reassurance.  You're right, I don't have to re-enter the address on subsequent visits.  I don't suppose you know the "name" of the relevant cookie? I was hoping to find a server-side config file I could set in advance.  I'm going to hold off on filing a bug report, as I suspect my problem is related to the fact that AWS EC2 instances have private and public IP addresses and I don't have a very deep understanding of routing, DNS, etc.